# javascript: how to make input selected

Tags: javascript, html

i have to use the following function, to change the input's type

```
    <input class="input" id="pas" type="text" name="password" style="color: #797272;" 
                                value= "<?php if ($_POST[password] != '') {echo '';}
                                        else {echo 'Ծածկաբառ';}?>"   
                                 onclick="if (this.value =='Ծածկաբառ') {
                                                                             this.value='';
                                                                             this.style.color='black';
                                                                             change();
                                                                             }" 
                                                                             />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() 
        {
            var input=document.getElementById('pas');
            var input2= input.cloneNode(false);
            input2.type='password';
            input.parentNode.replaceChild(input2,input);
        }
</script>
```

it works fine, but i have to reclick on input, because it creates a new input.
so what can i do, if i want it to create a new input with cursor in it?
thanks

### update::

```
input2.focus(); doesn't work in IE7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function change() 
        {
            var input=document.getElementById('pas');
            var input2= input.cloneNode(false);
            input2.type='password';
            input.parentNode.replaceChild(input2,input);
            input2.focus() <-- here you set the focus
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input2.focus();
```